"Can't load feature extractor for 'facebook/wav2vec2-large-960h-lv60-self" Error when I try to extract Audio Features
The Code
processor = Wav2Vec2Processor.from_pretrained("facebook/wav2vec2-large-960h-lv60-self")
model = Wav2Vec2Model.from_pretrained("facebook/wav2vec2-large-960h-lv60-self")
model.config.output_hidden_states = True

The Error
Can't load feature extractor for 'facebook/wav2vec2-large-960h-lv60-self'. If you were trying to load it from 'https://huggingface.co/models', make sure you don't have a local directory with the same name. Otherwise, make sure 'facebook/wav2vec2-large-960h-lv60-self' is the correct path to a directory containing a preprocessor_config.json file

When I try to extract features using HuggingFace, I get this error. I tried to fix this taking int consideration the Tokenizer error. But I am not able to fix it. Can someone help?
I need to extract the audio features using this Model.
